# Screen freezes and only cursor moves

Tags: 20.04

Sometimes when I switch between different activities suddenly the screen freezes and only the cursor moves. And everytime rebooting is very annoying.What is the solution to this issue?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? This may happen when the system runs out of RAM, and uses swap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out first if the machine has crashed, or if something has frozen the gui. Sometimes the machine can crash but the mouse still moves because its controlled from graphics hardware. Once you narrow that down, then you can try and investigate more. Setup your machine so that it allows you to ssh into it. SSH from another machine, and see if you can get a shell prompt. If you don't have another machine, there is an android app called termux that you can do this with. Figure out your IP address on the local network and SSH into it. Once you've sshed in, you could try killing apps one by one. If you can't ssh in, then you'll need to figure out why your OS is crashing, whether it be some hardware incompatibility, or you overclocked it too much or whatever. If killing apps doesn't help, maybe your graphics hardware has incompatibilities with your X server.